# PHP Curl returning url stripping out &times (decoding/encoding)

Tags: php, curl, html-entities, html-encode

I have searched and searched for a solution but cannot find it. I have a curl post request and that request returns a url. The url has a parameter in it named timestamp... It is converting the &timestamp to an xtamp as if it is encoding the &times to x (multiplication). I need to prevent this from happening. I need the raw data but the Curl is returning

```
https://example.com?var=4134134341xtamp=1235341431341
```

when it should be returning

```
https://example.com?var=4134134341&timestamp=1235341431341
```

I need to fix this so I get a complete url. Here is my code:

```
 //
  $data = array(
     'partnerId' => '2445584555550',
     'customerId' => '091874314838'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.xyz.com/connect/v2/generate");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Accept: */*','Accept-Encoding : gzip', 'xyz-App-Key:2b152a934f248ec62584852e5997e93', 'Accept:application/json', 'xyz-App-Token:'.$tk));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
//
echo $response;
echo "<pre>";print_r($response);
print_r($response['link']);
```

As you can see I have tried to echo it out in a few different ways but its still converting my &timestamp to xtamp and breaking my url. Please help and thank you very much.

Comment: Show us a simple `echo $response;` please Before you do any json conversion on it

Answer (score 1):

`curl` isn't doing this, the browser is interpreting `&times` in the URL as the HTML entity `&times;`, and rendering it as the × character.

To avoid this, and also to prevent XSS exploits, always use `htmlspecialchars()` when displaying text that may contain special characters.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($response, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED | ENT_HTML5);
```

Comment: as of PHP8.1.0, you're correct, htmlspecialchars is sufficient to protect against XSS, but prior to 8.1.0, you need something like ```htmlspecialchars($response, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED | ENT_HTML5)``` to properly protect against XSS. here is a htmlspecialchars bypass example in PHP <8.1.0: https://3v4l.org/7ZpJO